# merging the cells with the same value as one

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have data which gives me the months and their respective weeks splitted.
I want to merge the cells as one for their respective months.

for example

my data is like this

```
july   july    july   july   july   aug   aug
1-7    8-14    15-21  22-28  29-3   4-10  11-17......
```

it should display as

```
            july                               aug
1-7    8-14   15-21  22-28  29-3       4-10  11-17.....
```

both my month and weeks are generated dynamically, so, i cant say the exact position.
how i can calculate the position and merge the cells get it in macros in excel?

Comment: it should be possible through the `n` number of columns and then find the same column header. Then you could use the merge command to merge these cells.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on SE someone described merged cells (I think quite accurately) along the lines of “a creation of the Devil to try us beyond endurance”. Where used they could often be avoided by using Center Across Selection. In you case however I would suggest not bothering to find the position but merely blanking repeats after finding the first instance (therefore regardless of which month that is) which hopefully would make the code much simpler.